# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 13, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-macros

This is my first time working with javascript and I'm just messing around in google sheets.

Currently, I have a 2D array which contains all of the names of the sheets in the first position and some ranges within those sheets in the second position, I'm trying to step through the array and change all of the spaces within the ranges to 0. I've got it to a point where the script changes the first ranges of the sheets to 0 barring the last 2 sheets for some reason

```
function CompButton(){
  var event = 0
  var sheets = [
    ['Rebel_Outpost',"D6:D14","D18:D23","I6:I13","I17","I21:I23","N6:N22","N26:N34","S6:S21","S26:S31"],
    ['Advanced_Rebel',"D6:D9","D13","D17","D21:D25","I6:I20","I24","I28","N6:N20"],
    ['Market',"D7:D16","D20:D23","J7:J12","J16:J18","J22:J24","P7:P17","P21:P29"],
    ['Civilian_Shops',"D6:D18","D22:D36","I6:I12","I16","I20:I26","I30:I32","N6:N15","S6:S23","S30:S36"],
    ['Ground_Vehicles',"D7:D13","D17:D26","D30:D34","G7:G13","G17:G26","G30:G34"],
    ['Air_Vehicles',"D7:D22","G7:G22"],
    ['Water_Vehicles',"D7:D11","G7:G11"] 
  ];
  while (event < 7){
    for (var i = 1; i < sheets[event][i].length; i++){
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheets[event][0]); 
      sheet.getRange(sheets[event][1]).setValue(0);
      event++;
    }
  }
}
```

https://gyazo.com/3f59c6fda652681667010058092c8ae7

if u want access to the sheet to test ill post it below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bv6Fn6oKw4KaEM-xke0dOd87nVw2xk3W42Nnc1sKdJQ/edit?usp=sharing

https://script.google.com/d/12LMcV_meIdGgKANTeQjPcfMr2wC2ZdlZp_jxPRTAyCLTR8kJUHDuBbmu/edit?mid=ACjPJvE8t2PeFTxeOvw1nJ3Wif_B9lFXlFGCTluqR7XBLSsC9zWuQYo-ou_c1cJYw1MUP2njhNE-aZMqJ0NaJBspj91BQfD_p-o5n3JK6WgK2LZ_Sbjba5cTSN-qDOB9M5tYJy0KtE5DABw&uiv=2

Comment: You have only 7 array elements not 9, so change it to while(event < 7)

Comment: true, I added extra just in case something was wrong with it

Comment: And you are incrementing event inside for loop, not outside it

Comment: It should be inside while, but outside for

Comment: What @rksh1997 mentioned is the critical error—you need to move `event++` out of the for loop.

Comment: like this? https://gyazo.com/8a59531f03f35b1642790eedbb240153

Comment: That `sheets[event][i].length` seems odd. I mean, `console.log(sheets[0][1])` will print `"D6:D14"` and the for loop will iterate based in that string length. Also, you are using both a `while` loop and a `for` loop for the same purpose that is going through an array

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now:

```js
var sheets = [
  ['Rebel_Outpost',"D6:D14","D18:D23","I6:I13","I17","I21:I23","N6:N22","N26:N34","S6:S21","S26:S31"],
  ['Advanced_Rebel',"D6:D9","D13","D17","D21:D25","I6:I20","I24","I28","N6:N20"],
  ['Market',"D7:D16","D20:D23","J7:J12","J16:J18","J22:J24","P7:P17","P21:P29"],
  ['Civilian_Shops',"D6:D18","D22:D36","I6:I12","I16","I20:I26","I30:I32","N6:N15","S6:S23","S30:S36"],
  ['Ground_Vehicles',"D7:D13","D17:D26","D30:D34","G7:G13","G17:G26","G30:G34"],
  ['Air_Vehicles',"D7:D22","G7:G22"],
  ['Water_Vehicles',"D7:D11","G7:G11"] 
];

function zeroRanges(sheetsArray) {
  for(var sheetItem of sheetsArray) {
    var sheetName=sheetItem[0];
    console.log("Working on sheet \""+sheetName+"\"");
    for(var rangeItemIndex=1; rangeItemIndex<sheetItem.length; rangeItemIndex++) {
      var range=sheetItem[rangeItemIndex];
      console.log("--Zeroing range\""+range+"\"");
      // uncomment next 2 lines
      // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName); 
      // sheet.getRange(range).setValue(0);
    }
  }
}

zeroRanges(sheets);
```

I wrote a function, `zeroRanges` that you pass the `sheets` to by using `zeroRanges(sheets)`.  This way you can re-use it.
When you copy the code, uncomment the 2 lines that use the `SpreadsheetApp` - I've commented them out here so we can see in the console log that the function is working (hoping the commented code is correct).
You can comment-out/remove the `console.log` lines.

Comment: because im new to this and ive done a little bit of python before, if I'm not wrong, the event was to be added by 1 every time it had gone through the sheet (event)  and stepped through all of the ranges (i) right?

Comment: You are not wrong, but there are only 7 sheets in your example, yet you are checking <9...
I see you've since edited your code quote...
Anyways, I've edited my answer and added stuff - check it out again.

Comment: i would need it to find the sheet by name and then set all of the cells in the ranges of that particular sheet to 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here but perhaps you'll find the below syntax more readable.

```
sheets.map(sheet => {
    sheet.map((el, index) => {
        if(index !== 0) {
            // Perform operation on el
        }
    })
})
```

For reference see [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

This post might not answer the original question but it certainly would help as an alternative.